# How to have two similar Delimiters

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++ UDL, How can I have both of these delimiters?

```
[[  ]]
```

and

```
[[  ]]:
```

In this syntax (for Squiffy) the double brackets with a colon represents a section, whereas the double brackets without the colon represents a link to a section.

I'm trying to get them to colour separately, but when I add both delimiters in the UDL window, the one without the colon always seems to take precedence and I can't get different colours for each one.

Actually, what happens, is that the `:` doesn't matter. If I use the second designation with the `:` it hightlights them all no matter if the text has the `:` or not.

Comment: Seem buggy.

doc:
https://ivan-radic.github.io/udl-documentation/delimiters/

Comment: Here's my post on the npp help forum: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/20379/udl-similar-delimiters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, never could get them to have separate colours.

I ended up with this, which would colourize both `[ ]` and `[[ ]]`

```
Open:  (( [[ [ ))
Escape:
Close:  (( ]] ] ))
```

It didn't seem to matter if I used `:` in the closing delimiter or not.  I don't think the parser looks at that character combination.

[Here is my thread in the np++ forum](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/20379/udl-similar-delimiters).